# Can I integrate a custom JavaScript payment method in magento2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.3

I need to integrate a custom `payment gateway` in `magento2`. The payment gateway is fully dependent on `JAVASCRIPT`.

Comment: Yes you can integrate

Comment: but i have to work with complete JS library and i am only able to require single JS script. which is not working but if i use it on plain html file it works great. what can be the issue?

Comment: I think you have to define payment mehtod for magento